# Sweave.sty Rd.sty on texlive 2011 (OpenSUSE 12.1)

Tags: installing, texlive, sweave, paths

I am trying to make `Sweave.sty` and `Rd.sty` globally available on my system. After reading related posts on StackExchange, I changed `texmf.cnf`, so that

```
kpsewhich --expand-var='$TEXMF'
```

results in

```
{/home/philipp/texmf,!!/etc/texmf,!!/var/lib/texmf,!!/usr/lib/texmf,!!/usr/local/share/texmf,!!/usr/share/texmf,/usr/lib64/R/share/texmf/tex/latex}
```

The last directory is where R puts `Sweave.sty` and `Rd.sty`, and I also tried the variant with

```
!!
```

before this path. After

```
sudo texhash
```

and (just to be certain)

```
sudo mktexlsr
```

appropriate `ls-R` files are created. Nevertheless

```
kpsewhich Sweave.sty
```

still does not find the file, even with the

```
--must-exist
```

option. After trying all this I am stuck. I suspect there is some trouble because texlive and OpenSUSE are said not to mix well (especially when it comes to adding packages), but do not have the faintest clue.

Comment: you can make a symbolic link from R's directory to `~/texmf`, then you do not need complicated configurations like you did

Comment: @Yihui I know that there are all sorts of workarounds. Your suggestion works in my case, since I am the only user. But nevertheless it does not explain why `kpsewhich` fails.

Comment: I meanwhile figured it out: you must **not** add the full path to `Sweave.sty` to `texmf.cnf`. You must only add the path up to the `texmf` folder. So in my case it should have been: `/usr/lib64/R/share/texmf/` instead of `/usr/lib64/R/share/texmf/tex/latex`.

Comment: I suggest you add your comment as an answer and accept it, since it is actually the right way to do. By the way, you shouldn't leave a trailing slash: `.../texmf` rather than `.../texmf/` since `kpathsea` will add `/tex/latex` which would result in a double slash `texmf//tex/latex` and double slashes happen to have a special meaning (search recursively) for `kpathsea`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I meanwhile figured it out: you must not add the full path to `Sweave.sty` to `texmf.cnf`. You must only add the path up to the texmf folder. So in my case it should have been: `/usr/lib64/R/share/texmf` instead of `/usr/lib64/R/share/texmf/tex/latex`